# What does provide() do in angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular

what exactly role of provide?

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {provide} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

bootstrap(AppComponent,[provide('SECURITY_KEY',{useValue:'123abc'})]);
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide

Comment: Thanks @mic4ael but this link contains AngularJS(ie Angular 1) $provide description :)

Comment: @SarveshYadav I would highly recommend you to go through this [article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: The provide function seems to be gone. Current syntax is simply: `{ provide: ''SECURITY_KEY', useValue: '123abc' }`. See also the link above by @PankajParkar

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, it creates a Provider. See the end of the code below:

````
import { Type } from '../facade/lang';
/**
 * Describes how the {@link Injector} should instantiate a given token.
 *
 * See {@link provide}.
 *
 * ### Example ([live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/GNAyj6K6PfYg2NBzgwZ5?p%3Dpreview&p=preview))
 *
 * ```javascript
 * var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
 *   new Provider("message", { useValue: 'Hello' })
 * ]);
 *
 * expect(injector.get("message")).toEqual('Hello');
 * ```
 * @ts2dart_const
 * @deprecated
 */
export declare class Provider {
    /**
     * Token used when retrieving this provider. Usually, it is a type {@link Type}.
     */
    token: any;
    /**
     * Binds a DI token to an implementation class.
     *
     * ### Example ([live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RSTG86qgmoxCyj9SWPwY?p=preview))
     *
     * Because `useExisting` and `useClass` are often confused, the example contains
     * both use cases for easy comparison.
     *
     * ```typescript
     * class Vehicle {}
     *
     * class Car extends Vehicle {}
     *
     * var injectorClass = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
     *   Car,
     *   {provide: Vehicle,  useClass: Car }
     * ]);
     * var injectorAlias = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
     *   Car,
     *   {provide: Vehicle,  useExisting: Car }
     * ]);
     *
     * expect(injectorClass.get(Vehicle)).not.toBe(injectorClass.get(Car));
     * expect(injectorClass.get(Vehicle) instanceof Car).toBe(true);
     *
     * expect(injectorAlias.get(Vehicle)).toBe(injectorAlias.get(Car));
     * expect(injectorAlias.get(Vehicle) instanceof Car).toBe(true);
     * ```
     */
    useClass: Type;
    /**
     * Binds a DI token to a value.
     *
     * ### Example ([live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/UFVsMVQIDe7l4waWziES?p=preview))
     *
     * ```javascript
     * var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
     *   new Provider("message", { useValue: 'Hello' })
     * ]);
     *
     * expect(injector.get("message")).toEqual('Hello');
     * ```
     */
    useValue: any;
    /**
     * Binds a DI token to an existing token.
     *
     * {@link Injector} returns the same instance as if the provided token was used.
     * This is in contrast to `useClass` where a separate instance of `useClass` is returned.
     *
     * ### Example ([live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/QsatsOJJ6P8T2fMe9gr8?p=preview))
     *
     * Because `useExisting` and `useClass` are often confused the example contains
     * both use cases for easy comparison.
     *
     * ```typescript
     * class Vehicle {}
     *
     * class Car extends Vehicle {}
     *
     * var injectorAlias = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
     *   Car,
     *   {provide: Vehicle,  useExisting: Car }
     * ]);
     * var injectorClass = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
     *   Car,
     *   {provide: Vehicle,  useClass: Car }
     * ]);
     *
     * expect(injectorAlias.get(Vehicle)).toBe(injectorAlias.get(Car));
     * expect(injectorAlias.get(Vehicle) instanceof Car).toBe(true);
     *
     * expect(injectorClass.get(Vehicle)).not.toBe(injectorClass.get(Car));
     * expect(injectorClass.get(Vehicle) instanceof Car).toBe(true);
     * ```
     */
    useExisting: any;
    /**
     * Binds a DI token to a function which computes the value.
     *
     * ### Example ([live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Scoxy0pJNqKGAPZY1VVC?p=preview))
     *
     * ```typescript
     * var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
     *   {provide: Number,  useFactory: () => { return 1+2; }},
     *   new Provider(String, { useFactory: (value) => { return "Value: " + value; },
     *                       deps: [Number] })
     * ]);
     *
     * expect(injector.get(Number)).toEqual(3);
     * expect(injector.get(String)).toEqual('Value: 3');
     * ```
     *
     * Used in conjunction with dependencies.
     */
    useFactory: Function;
    /**
     * Specifies a set of dependencies
     * (as `token`s) which should be injected into the factory function.
     *
     * ### Example ([live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Scoxy0pJNqKGAPZY1VVC?p=preview))
     *
     * ```typescript
     * var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
     *   {provide: Number,  useFactory: () => { return 1+2; }},
     *   new Provider(String, { useFactory: (value) => { return "Value: " + value; },
     *                       deps: [Number] })
     * ]);
     *
     * expect(injector.get(Number)).toEqual(3);
     * expect(injector.get(String)).toEqual('Value: 3');
     * ```
     *
     * Used in conjunction with `useFactory`.
     */
    dependencies: Object[];
    constructor(token: any, {useClass, useValue, useExisting, useFactory, deps, multi}: {
        useClass?: Type;
        useValue?: any;
        useExisting?: any;
        useFactory?: Function;
        deps?: Object[];
        multi?: boolean;
    });
    /**
     * Creates multiple providers matching the same token (a multi-provider).
     *
     * Multi-providers are used for creating pluggable service, where the system comes
     * with some default providers, and the user can register additional providers.
     * The combination of the default providers and the additional providers will be
     * used to drive the behavior of the system.
     *
     * ### Example
     *
     * ```typescript
     * var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
     *   new Provider("Strings", { useValue: "String1", multi: true}),
     *   new Provider("Strings", { useValue: "String2", multi: true})
     * ]);
     *
     * expect(injector.get("Strings")).toEqual(["String1", "String2"]);
     * ```
     *
     * Multi-providers and regular providers cannot be mixed. The following
     * will throw an exception:
     *
     * ```typescript
     * var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
     *   new Provider("Strings", { useValue: "String1", multi: true }),
     *   new Provider("Strings", { useValue: "String2"})
     * ]);
     * ```
     */
    multi: boolean;
}
/**
 * See {@link Provider} instead.
 *
 * @deprecated
 * @ts2dart_const
 */
export declare class Binding extends Provider {
    constructor(token: any, {toClass, toValue, toAlias, toFactory, deps, multi}: {
        toClass?: Type;
        toValue?: any;
        toAlias?: any;
        toFactory: Function;
        deps?: Object[];
        multi?: boolean;
    });
    /**
     * @deprecated
     */
    toClass: Type;
    /**
     * @deprecated
     */
    toAlias: any;
    /**
     * @deprecated
     */
    toFactory: Function;
    /**
     * @deprecated
     */
    toValue: any;
}
/**
 * Creates a {@link Provider}.
 *
 * To construct a {@link Provider}, bind a `token` to either a class, a value, a factory function,
 * or
 * to an existing `token`.
 * See {@link ProviderBuilder} for more details.
 *
 * The `token` is most commonly a class or {@link OpaqueToken-class.html}.
 *
 * @deprecated
 */
export declare function bind(token: any): ProviderBuilder;
/**
 * Helper class for the {@link bind} function.
 * @deprecated
 */
export declare class ProviderBuilder {
    token: any;
    constructor(token: any);
    /**
     * Binds a DI token to a class.
     *
     * ### Example ([live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZpBCSYqv6e2ud5KXLdxQ?p=preview))
     *
     * Because `toAlias` and `toClass` are often confused, the example contains
     * both use cases for easy comparison.
     *
     * ```typescript
     * class Vehicle {}
     *
     * class Car extends Vehicle {}
     *
     * var injectorClass = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
     *   Car,
     *   {provide: Vehicle, useClass: Car}
     * ]);
     * var injectorAlias = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
     *   Car,
     *   {provide: Vehicle, useExisting: Car}
     * ]);
     *
     * expect(injectorClass.get(Vehicle)).not.toBe(injectorClass.get(Car));
     * expect(injectorClass.get(Vehicle) instanceof Car).toBe(true);
     *
     * expect(injectorAlias.get(Vehicle)).toBe(injectorAlias.get(Car));
     * expect(injectorAlias.get(Vehicle) instanceof Car).toBe(true);
     * ```
     */
    toClass(type: Type): Provider;
    /**
     * Binds a DI token to a value.
     *
     * ### Example ([live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/G024PFHmDL0cJFgfZK8O?p=preview))
     *
     * ```typescript
     * var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
     *   {provide: 'message', useValue: 'Hello'}
     * ]);
     *
     * expect(injector.get('message')).toEqual('Hello');
     * ```
     */
    toValue(value: any): Provider;
    /**
     * Binds a DI token to an existing token.
     *
     * Angular will return the same instance as if the provided token was used. (This is
     * in contrast to `useClass` where a separate instance of `useClass` will be returned.)
     *
     * ### Example ([live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/uBaoF2pN5cfc5AfZapNw?p=preview))
     *
     * Because `toAlias` and `toClass` are often confused, the example contains
     * both use cases for easy comparison.
     *
     * ```typescript
     * class Vehicle {}
     *
     * class Car extends Vehicle {}
     *
     * var injectorAlias = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
     *   Car,
     *   {provide: Vehicle, useExisting: Car}
     * ]);
     * var injectorClass = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
     *   Car,
     *   {provide: Vehicle, useClass: Car})
     * ]);
     *
     * expect(injectorAlias.get(Vehicle)).toBe(injectorAlias.get(Car));
     * expect(injectorAlias.get(Vehicle) instanceof Car).toBe(true);
     *
     * expect(injectorClass.get(Vehicle)).not.toBe(injectorClass.get(Car));
     * expect(injectorClass.get(Vehicle) instanceof Car).toBe(true);
     * ```
     */
    toAlias(aliasToken: any): Provider;
    /**
     * Binds a DI token to a function which computes the value.
     *
     * ### Example ([live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/OejNIfTT3zb1iBxaIYOb?p=preview))
     *
     * ```typescript
     * var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
     *   {provide: Number, useFactory: () => { return 1+2; }},
     *   {provide: String, useFactory: (v) => { return "Value: " + v; }, deps: [Number]}
     * ]);
     *
     * expect(injector.get(Number)).toEqual(3);
     * expect(injector.get(String)).toEqual('Value: 3');
     * ```
     */
    toFactory(factory: Function, dependencies?: any[]): Provider;
}
/**
 * Creates a {@link Provider}.
 *
 * See {@link Provider} for more details.
 *
 * <!-- TODO: improve the docs -->
 * @deprecated
 */
export declare function provide(token: any, {useClass, useValue, useExisting, useFactory, deps, multi}: {
    useClass?: Type;
    useValue?: any;
    useExisting?: any;
    useFactory?: Function;
    deps?: Object[];
    multi?: boolean;
}): Provider;
````

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of providers:

> Injector providers
>
> A provider provides the concrete, runtime version of a dependency
>   value. The injector relies on providers to create instances of the
>   services that the injector injects into components and other services.
>
> We must register a service provider with the injector, or it won't
>   know how to create the service.

And we have one injector per component as described here:

> Each component instance gets its own injector and an injector at one
>   level is a child injector of the injector above it in the tree.
>
> When a component at the bottom requests a dependency, Angular tries to
>   satisfy that dependency with a provider registered in that component's
>   own injector. If the component's injector lacks the provider, it
>   passes the request up to its parent component's injector. If that
>   injector can't satisfy the request, it passes it along to its parent
>   component's injector. The requests keep bubbling up until we find an
>   injector that can handle the request or run out of component
>   ancestors. If we run out of ancestors, Angular throws an error.

In these case is instructing the "top level" injector that it will be able to provide instances of those types (or values as in this case). Then to wrap up: a provider configures an injector and you have an injector per component. In this case you are configuring AppComponent to provide the value of SECURITY_KEY.

Now you are wondering: why?, why do I need to write this (apparently) boilerplate code?: The thing is that you can configure an injector in such way (with a factory) that it will return an instance that conforms to an interface but that lets you change the specific behaviour. Do you remember the example of `Car` interface with implementations such as `Tesla`, `Volkswagen`...?. Yes as simple as that.

sources:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#injector-providers